# Multiply two tables by ordering one table first then multiplying

Tags: sql, integer, multiplication

This is what I have:

Table 1

```
CB / A / B / C
X / 5 / 2 / 1
Y / 2 / 3 / 0
```

Table 2

```
CB / FL_X / FL_A / FL_V
X / 0.2 / 0.3 / 0.5   ---> (sum up to 1)
Y / 0/45 / 0.55 / Null ---> (sum up to 1)
```

Now I want to multiply this two tables to get:

Table result:

```
CB / FL / A / B / C
X / X / 0 / 0 / 0
X / A / 2 / 1 / 0
X / V / 3 / 1 / 1
Y / X / 1 / 2 / 0
Y / A / 1 / 1 / 0
```

As you can see numbers in table 1 and results are integers. so I have to use the "round" function. and the sum of each CB in table result should be the same as table 1. For example (CB(X, A) = FL_X(A)+FL_A(A)+FL_V(A) --> 5 (From table 1) = 0 + 2 + 3 (From table result). As you can see FL_V(A) is 0.5*5=2.5 if i round it it would be 3. If I do the same for FL_A(A) --> 0.3*5=1.5~2. 3+2=5; therefore although FL_X(A) which is 0.2*5=1 it would be 0 in the results because the sums should equal to table 1. This is done by ordering table 2 by values first.

This was an example of a much smaller table than I have.

Could you help me write the sql query for this process?

Answer (score 0):

1. Break the table 2 columns 'X/A/V' into multiple rows. You didn't mention the RDBMS you use. If it is SQL Server 2005+ this is exactly what UNPIVOT does. Here's a simple example and explanation: [UNPIVOT](http://learnsqlserver.in/5/Unpivot.aspx)
2. Now it's only a matter of joining the table 1 with the result of step 1 (on the CB column)

So the partial answer (no rounding) looks something like this (assuming SQL Server):

```
SELECT 
  T3.CB, T3.FL, 
  T3.Ratio * T1.A, T3.Ratio * T1.B, T3.Ratio * T1.C
FROM
  (SELECT CB, FL_X, FL_A, FL_V FROM Table2) T2
UNPIVOT 
  (Ratio FOR FL IN ([FL_X], [FL_A], [FL_V])) AS T3
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 
  ON T1.CB = T3.CB
```

The hardest problem in your question is making sure that the new numbers add up exactly to the same sum as the original ones. Floating-point arithmetic is pretty tricky. You cannot consistently ROUND or CEIL or FLOOR the results. E.g.: starting number is 1, ratio is 0.3/0.3/0.3. If you round everything down the sum becomes 0. Similarly if starting number is 2, you round everything from 0.6 to 1 and the new sum becomes 3. Another example is with halves. If you start with 1 and the ratios are 0.5/0.5/0, the sum becomes 0 or 2, depending on whether you round the midpoint up or down.

The solution is to perform a cumulative sum to be sure that there is no rounding errors. In your case, with a limited set of 3 values, it could go something like this:

```
SELECT 
  T1.CB, 
  -- Compute the decomposition of A into X/A/V. X_A + A_A + V_A should always be exactly A.
  ROUND(T2.FL_X * T1.A) AS X_A,
  ROUND((T2.FL_X + T2.FL_A) * T1.A) - ROUND(T2.FL_X * T1.A) AS A_A,
  T1.A - ROUND((T2.FL_X + T2.FL_A) * T1.A) AS V_A
  -- similarly for T1.B and T1.C
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.CB = T2.CB
```

Now you only have to combine both parts of the answer (i.e. unpivot the results of the second query).